# What is the use of taking $t\in (0,1)$ in proving monotone convergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Let $(X, S, \mu)$ be a measure space.Let $0\le f_1\le...$ be an increasing sequence of $S$ measurable functions. Define $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ by $f=\lim_n f_n$.

Then $\lim_{k\to \infty} \int f_k = \int f.$

**Proof**: $f$ is measurable as it is limit of measurable functions. $\forall x\in X, f_k(x)\le f(x)\implies \int f_k\le \int f$.

Now the proof goes along the following lines: Choose $c_i\in [0,\infty)$ and disjoint sets $A_i$, $i=1,2,...,m$ in $S$ such that $f(x)\ge \sum_{i=1}^m c_i \chi_{A_i}(x)$.

Take any $t\in (0,1)$ (**I don't understand why this is required. I think one could take $t=1$ at this stage.**). Define for every $k\in \mathbb N$, $E_k=\{x\in X: f_k(x)\ge t\sum_{i=1}^m c_i \chi_{A_i}(x)\}.$

Now, $E_k$'s are increasing and $\bigcup_k E_k=X$; so for every $j$, we have $\lim_k \mu(A_j\cap E_k)=\mu(A_j)$. $f_k(x)\ge t\sum_{i=1}^m c_i \chi_{A_i\bigcap E_k}(x)$ for every $x\in X$.

Then it follows that $\int f_k\ge t\sum_{i=1}^m c_i \mu(A_i\bigcap E_k)\implies \lim_k\int f_k\ge t\sum_{i=1}^m c_i\mu(A_i).$ Taking sup over the disjoint sets $A_i$ and $c_i$'s we get $\lim_k\int f_k\le t\int f$. Letting $t\to 1$ proves the statement.

Suppose that I take $t=1$ in the beginning itself.  Then also the proof works as we get $\cup_k E_k=X$ (**pf:** Take any $x\in X$. If $x\in A_i$ for some $i$, then $f(x)\ge c_i$. Hence, there exists some $k$ such that $f_k(x)\ge c_i\implies x\in E_k$, where $E_k=\{x\in X: f_k(x)\ge \sum_{i=1}^m c_i \chi_{A_i}(x)\}$ ($t=1$). So $x\in \bigcup_k E_k$) And $E_i$'s are increasing as before. Rest of the steps are word for word with $t=1$.

So my question is: why was $t\in (0,1)$ taken in the beginning and then $t\to 1$ was done later?

Please help me understand this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

'$f(x)\ge c_i$. Hence, there exists some $k$ such that $f_k(x)\ge c_i$':

This is wrong. If $f(x)=c_i$ we can have $f_k(x) <c_i$ for every $k$ but still have $f_k(x) \to f(x)$. (For example, $1-\frac 1 n <1$ for all $n$ but $\lim (1-\frac 1n )=1$ (so $\lim (1-\frac 1n )\geq 1$).

Comment: I was thinking: suppose $x_n\to L$. $L>0\implies x_n>0$ for some $n$. Proof: Suppose on the contrary $x_n\le 0$  for all $n$. Then, $L\le 0$, a contradiction. I see that I need strict inequality to pass that claim. But still, I don't understand how introducing $t$ helps there.

Comment: The point is you only have $f(x) \geq c_i$. If you had $f(x) >c_i$ that would work To get strict inequality you have to use $f(x) >tc_i$ where $0<t<1$ @Koro

Comment: I think you meant $f_k$ instead of $f$.

Comment: I understood now why. So take any $x\in X$. If $x\in A_i$ for some $i$, then $f(x)\ge c_i$. Suppose on the contrary that $f_k(x)< tc_i$ for all $k$, then $f(x)\le tc_i<c_i$, a contradiction. So this is what $t$ is for. Thank you so much.